# Estimate breakpoint until convergence

Tags: r, regression, repeat, breakpoints, estimation

I have the following data:

```
> str(sample)
'data.frame':   500 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ predictor: num  0.446 0.395 0.484 0.919 0.844 ...
 $ response : num  6.65 6.22 6.54 7.85 7.34 ...
```

I need to estimate the breakpoint used in stepwise regression, I am following the algorithm of Muggeo (2003). This is a plot of the predictor versus the response:

[image: predvsresponse]

I have created the following function:

```
breakpoint<-function(psi,data){
repeat{
  psi<-psi
  predictor<-data[,1]
  response<-data[,2]
  
  U<-ifelse(predictor>=psi,predictor-psi,0)
  V<-ifelse(predictor>=psi,-1,0)
  
  model<-lm(response~predictor+U+V,data=data)
  psi_new<-(model$coefficients[4]/model$coefficients[3])+psi
  psi<-psi_new
  if (abs(psi-psi_new)<0.00001 && model$coefficients[4]<0.00001) break
}
  result<-c(psi,model$coefficients[4])
  return(result)
}
```

However, the function is extremely sensitive to the initial value of psi, I am unsure why this would be. I think it might be to do with my convergence criteria. The function should converge when the "gap" between psi and psi_new is negligible and when the coefficient for V is basically zero.

The correct breakpoint determined by the package segmented is 0.27, when I input a psi of 0.25 I get the correct value, but when I input 0.4, the estimate changes to 0.32.

Comment: Can you please help us to help you by prodiving reproducible toy data, e.g. by generating artificial data?

Comment: I have done so now.

Comment: ... but the data has no breakpoint.

Comment: Ah of course, I am not sure how to simulate such data :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
## geneate some test data
set.seed(132)
predictor <- seq(0, 0.999, length.out = 500)
response  <- approx(c(0, 0.27, 1), c(6.5, 6, 8.5), predictor)$y + rnorm(predictor, sd = 0.2)
sample <- data.frame(predictor, response)

breakpoint <- function(psi, data, tol=1e-5, maxit=50){
  iterations <- 0
  predictor  <- data[,1]

  repeat{
    U <- ifelse(predictor >= psi, predictor - psi, 0)
    V <- ifelse(predictor >= psi,              -1, 0)

    model <- lm(response ~ predictor + U + V, data = data)
    p <- coef(model)
    psi_new <- (p[4]/p[3]) + psi
    psi <- psi_new
    if ((abs(psi - psi_new) < tol) & abs(p[4]) < tol) break
    if (iterations > maxit) {
      warning("too many iterations")
      break
    }
    iterations <- iterations + 1
  }
  result <- c(psi = unname(psi), p[4])
  return(result)
}

psi <- 0.1
breakpoint(psi, sample, tol=1e-5) # warning, but psi is ok
breakpoint(psi, sample, tol=1e-2) # no warning

plot(predictor, response, cex=0.5, pch=16)
abline(v=breakpoint(psi, sample, tol=1e-2)["psi"], lty="dashed", col="red")

## for comparison
library("segmented")
segmented(lm(response ~ predictor, data=sample))
```

In this example, the breakpoint was well identified, but optimization can in theory be trapped in a local minimum. Therefore, it may be wise to try different start values.

**Edit:**

- edited again, use `abs(p4)`
- maximum iteration count to avoid endless loop

[image: breakpoint identification]

Comment: I have added a picture of my plot. How do I ensure it converges to the global minimum?

Comment: With your edits, the function runs for extremely long, more than 2 minutes and it still hasn't converged. Does it work on your side?

Comment: You are right, it worked only in special cases. So we ned to have look into the original algorithm or just use the **segmented** package instead.

I edited my suggested solution again - no warranty.

Comment: Yes, I did that now too.  I specifically have to estimate the breakpoint using a function as I am then going to bootstrap it. Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: Of course **abs**: After debugging,  `abs(p[4])` is necessary, but tolerance should be increased (e.g. to 1e-2), if variability of the data is high. The original `segmented.lm` code is more tricky, but unfortunately not well readable.